# Represent schematically using the tikz package a "commutative" diagram where two of the "arrows" are circular loops

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Consider the diagram

[image]

where the clockwise circular arrows indicate `$M_{f^t}$` has a structure inherited from the structure of the R-module `$\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]`. I have tried to duplicate it as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large]
{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]} \arrow[rr, "t\mapsto s-m"'] \arrow[d]&& {\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[s]} \arrow[d] \\
M_{f^t} \arrow[rr, "{g(t,x)\cdot f^t \mapsto g(s-m,x)\cdot f^{s-m}}"'] && M_{f^s}      
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

but don't know how to make the circular arrows instead of the standard vertical ones and don't know how to get `$\sim$` (the squiggly line (`~`) indicating isomorphism) to appear over each horizontal arrow.

Comment: Please give the full compilable code of your attempt.

Comment: @AndréC: Sorry for not including it earlier; I have edited my post.

Comment: Can you change the title of the question in order to facilitate its indexing by search engines such as *"Represent schematically an isomorphism"* this will allow those who have the same problem as you to find your question and the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I propose to use a scaled version of `\circlearrowleft` on a phantom vertical arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large]
{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]} \arrow[rr, "t\mapsto s-m"'] \arrow[rr, phantom, shift left=1ex, swap, "\sim"]
\arrow[d, phantom, "\adjustbox{scale={2}{-2}}{$ \circlearrowleft $}" description]&& {\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[s]} \arrow[d, phantom, "\adjustbox{scale={2}{-2}}{$ \circlearrowleft $}" description] \\
M_{f^t} \arrow[rr, "{g(t,x)\cdot f^t \mapsto g(s-m,x)\cdot f^{s-m}}"'] \arrow[rr, phantom, shift left=1ex, swap, "\sim"]&& M_{f^s}
\end{tikzcd}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. This is exactly what I wanted. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: You don't have to thank me. It's a pleasure to help when I can.

Answer (score 10):

### Updating 1

....with some modifications.....to have a symmetrical loop.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\newcommand{\cir}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\circlearrowright$}}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0em, column sep=4.3em]
\underset{\scalebox{2}{\ensuremath{\cir}}}{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]} \arrow[rr, above, "\sim", "t\mapsto s-m"'] &  & \underset{\scalebox{2}{\ensuremath{\cir}}}{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[s]}\\[-.5em]
M_{f^t}\arrow[rr, above, "\sim", "{g(t,x)\cdot f^t \mapsto g(s-m,x)\cdot f^{s-m}}"'] &  & M_{f^s}
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

..... the final code ....

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\newcommand{\cir}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\circlearrowright$}}
\begin{document}


\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-.1em, column sep=4.3em]
\underset{\scalebox{3}{\ensuremath{\cir}}}{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]} \arrow[rr, above, "\sim", "t\mapsto s-m"'] &  & \underset{\scalebox{3}{\ensuremath{\cir}}}{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[s]}\\
M_{f^t}\arrow[rr, above, "\sim", "{g(t,x)\cdot f^t \mapsto g(s-m,x)\cdot f^{s-m}}"'] &  & M_{f^s}
\end{tikzcd}\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will see how this looks.

Comment: (After your final edit): Very nice. Thank you so much for your effort and attempt to help me.

Comment: @Mark Here we are a very strong and compact group; and it is a pleasure to help others.

Answer (score 9):

## Update 1: new loop `my loop`

as requested by Anush (I hope this will be convenient). The style of the loops is defined with:

```
\tikzset{my loop/.style={to path={.. controls +(130:2) and +(50:2) .. (\tikztotarget)}}}
```

[image: my loop/.style]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\tikzset{my loop/.style={to path={.. controls +(130:2) and +(50:2) .. (\tikztotarget)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large,]
{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]} \arrow[rr,"\sim", "t\mapsto s-m"'] && {\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[s]}  \\
|[alias=Z]|M_{f^t} \arrow[rr, "\sim","{g(t,x)\cdot f^t \mapsto g(s-m,x)\cdot f^{s-m}}"'] && M_{f^s}      
\arrow[my loop, from=2-1, to=2-1
]
\arrow[my loop, from=2-3, to=2-3]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

## Old answer

A solution that uses TikZ's native loops. The style of the loops is defined with: :

```
\tikzset{every loop/.style ={out=120,in=60,looseness=6,min distance=7mm}}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\tikzset{every loop/.style ={out=120,in=60,looseness=6,min distance=7mm}}

\begin{document}
%\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large,]
{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]} \arrow[rr,"\sim", "t\mapsto s-m"'] && {\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[s]}  \\
M_{f^t} \arrow[rr, "\sim","{g(t,x)\cdot f^t \mapsto g(s-m,x)\cdot f^{s-m}}"'] && M_{f^s}      
\arrow[loop, from=2-1, to=2-1]
\arrow[loop, from=2-3, to=2-3]
\end{tikzcd}
%\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to thank you for answering. That looks really good and would work very well.

Comment: You have the best looking loops!  The vertical space above the loops looks too much though.  I think it should be symmetric above and below the loops.

Comment: @Anush Thanks for the compliment. But I didn't quite understand what you mean by *"The vertical space above the loops looks too much though. I think it should be symmetric above and below the loops"*

Comment: @Anush Do you mean that the loop must be at equal distance from the two lines (upper and lower)?

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Comment: @Anush Is my update good enough for you?

Comment: Simply perfect.

Comment: @Anush Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\def\circleArrow{\tikz\draw[->] (0,0) arc[start angle=265,end angle=-85,radius=5mm];}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large]
{\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[t]} \arrow[rr,"\sim", "t\mapsto s-m"'] && {\mathscr{D}_{n,k}[s]}\\ 
\circleArrow && \circleArrow \\
M_{f^t} \arrow[rr, "\sim","{g(t,x)\cdot f^t \mapsto g(s-m,x)\cdot f^{s-m}}"'] && M_{f^s}      
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: diagram with circle arrows]

Comment: Is there a competition for this ahahaha code? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano A few minutes ago there were not aswers and when I post my answer there were three.

Comment: I'm joking....:-)

Comment: This is actually very nice as it shows how the circular arrow can be drawn with tikz instead of relying on `\circlearrowleft`. I wonder if the vertical space can be reduced.

Comment: @corwin.amber You can use the key `row sep=tiny`.